# How to make an Application for Google TV remote in Android Programming?

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io, television

I have to make Like this remote Application-:[Link of App Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.bouyguestelecom.remote&hl=en)

I don't have good english comm. that's why i shared a link like this i need to do so please suggest me to how to do approach.1st i was done the step i.e i created the key store and added the the key store now i want to search on same ip what are the devices but it's not detected i don't know why?

I used the reference the reference code from [Code Link](https://github.com/entertailion/Anymote-for-Java/tree/master/libs)

```
sendUserActionEvent() mView == null 09 - 29 14: 20: 02.741 1464 - 1464 / com.entertailion.android.anymote E / ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null 09 - 29 14: 20: 02.771 1464 - 3440 / com.entertailion.android.anymote E / anymote: ConnectingActivity: (IOE) Could not create socket to Unknown boxjava.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to / 10.10 .20 .52(port 9551): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED(Connection refused)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java: 124)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 183)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 163)
at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java: 590)
at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java: 128)
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 178)
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 150)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket. < init > (SSLSocket.java: 764)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl. < init > (OpenSSLSocketImpl.java: 205)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java: 68)
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.attemptToConnect(ConnectingTask.java: 360)
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.connect(ConnectingTask.java: 203)
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.run(ConnectingTask.java: 175)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED(Connection refused)
at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java: 111)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java: 137)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java: 122)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 183) 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 163) 
at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java: 590) 
at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java: 128) 
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 178) 
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 150) 
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket. < init > (SSLSocket.java: 764) 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl. < init > (OpenSSLSocketImpl.java: 205) 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java: 68) 
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.attemptToConnect(ConnectingTask.java: 360) 
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.connect(ConnectingTask.java: 203) 
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.run(ConnectingTask.java: 175)  09 - 29 14: 20: 02.821 1464 - 3440 / com.entertailion.android.anymote E / anymote: ConnectingActivity: Failed to connect
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to / 10.10 .20 .52(port 9552): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED(Connection refused)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java: 124)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 183)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 163)
at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java: 590)
at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java: 128)
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 178)
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 150)
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.attemptToPair(ConnectingTask.java: 260)
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.connect(ConnectingTask.java: 209)
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.run(ConnectingTask.java: 175)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED(Connection refused)
at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java: 111)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java: 137)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java: 122)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 183) 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 163) 
at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java: 590) 
at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java: 128) 
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 178) 
at java.net.Socket. < init > (Socket.java: 150) 
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.attemptToPair(ConnectingTask.java: 260) 
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.connect(ConnectingTask.java: 209) 
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.run(ConnectingTask.java: 175)  09 - 29 14: 20: 02.821 1464 - 3440 / com.entertailion.android.anymote I / anymote: ConnectingActivity: Pairing failed 09 - 29 14: 20: 02.821 1464 - 3440 / com.entertailion.android.anymote E / anymote: ConnectingActivity: run
java.lang.NullPointerException: null socket
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.client.AnymoteSender.attemptToConnect(AnymoteSender.java: 118)
at com.entertailion.java.anymote.connection.ConnectingTask.run(ConnectingTask.java: 177)
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as Anymote lib implementation is concerned it had clear API available for the reason.

From [Android-Anymote](https://github.com/entertailion/Android-Anymote) implementation in [MainActivity](https://github.com/entertailion/Android-Anymote/blob/master/src/com/entertailion/android/anymote/MainActivity.java) you can see on [Line No: 59](https://github.com/entertailion/Android-Anymote/blob/master/src/com/entertailion/android/anymote/MainActivity.java#L59) it is registering itself for possible connections. All available devices are available on [Line No: 319](https://github.com/entertailion/Android-Anymote/blob/master/src/com/entertailion/android/anymote/MainActivity.java#L319) method `onSelectDevice`, this is the list of all visible Google TV devices on the network.

Comment: In menifest file one activity is added i.e. PairingActivity but in src file it's not there.then how to get that PairingAcitvity. @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain

Comment: I used this one but it's not searched on same ip google tv.

Comment: Yes `PairingActivity` is missing from the source code, but I am confident there is no need for the pairing activity as `pairing` work is handled in `onConnected` method which is called when you select device from the `onSelectedDevice` list. Probably they forget to remove the listing from the manifest

Comment: It's not listing on same ip device.but it's local ip.

Comment: Now that is an another question, you need to debug the situation to find the problem. :)

Comment: ok i am debuggin but laterally if i am going to any problem may you help me?

Comment: You can always ask a new question if you are facing some other problem that is not already asked in the question, there are thousands of people and will help you out.

Comment: Your error is `failed to connect to / 10.10 .20 .52(port 9552)` means your system is unable to connect to your IP address

Comment: but when i check with other app it's detected and connected.that's why i don't know why not my app is connected but other apps connected.@Murtaza Khursheed Hussain

Comment: Also see your socket is `null` `java.lang.NullPointerException: null socket`

Comment: when i call socket.connect(ip,port); then it gives IOEXception by the time i don't know why?

Comment: may be your ip or port is blocked

Comment: so for that what i need to do ?so i need to change port number?or ip?

Comment: Dear ABC, you need to understand whats going under the hood to solve that said problem, just asking what to do doesn't do any good, asking someone to write your code for your is not going to happen. I have outlined all possible problems. just go through it and try to solve it

Comment: i already tried because of not getting solution then i post the problem.